# Rancher/Fleet GitRepo git ls-remote error

Tags: git, github, rancher, continuous-delivery, fleet

Within Rancher Continuous Delivery, I am seeing an error on polling the GitHub repository with the below error:

```
git ls-remote head master error exit status 128 detail ssh connect to host port 22 operation times out fatal could not read from remote repository please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists
```

Within the GitRepo item itself on the Rancher UI, the following can be seen within the resource:

[image]

I am using SSH authentication to a private enterprise GitHub repository. The access is intermittent (it will pick up changes when I pause/unpause or force the update). After some time, it will go into this state and will not pick up the changes in the repo until the forced update is done manually.

Comment: How often are you polling?  Are you using a webhook to determine changes and only polling then, or are you polling at a certain frequency?

Comment: @bk2204 within Rancher CD, I do not see a polling frequency option. So I am assuming it is using a web hook to determine changes. I realize that you can set this in Jenkins, and we have successfully used the repo with both polling at a frequency and GitSCM web hooks within Jenkins, but having issues with the Rancher Continuous Delivery configuration.